# RealTime Architecture(ARA) in Asterisk 1.6.2.1 & more?

Tags: asterisk

Currently i am using Asterisk version 1.6.2.1.
All settings is default (i installed & configure it as per tutorials in different forums).
So when in console i use following commands:-

```
astrisk -r
core show settings
```

then i find out Realtime Architecture (ARA): Disabled
So

1.how to enable it?

2.Is ARA by default enable in Asterisk version 1.6.X & above or by default it disable & we have to enable it?

```
 app_set=1.6
```

3. I try in asterisk.conf there is line

`pbx_realtime=1.6`

`res_agi=1.6`

`app_set=1.6`

I convert  to  1.4, but no use.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have reviewed:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime
http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/I_section12_tt1465.html

What database access method are you using?  ODBC?  MySQL?  Can you access the database via the credentials you've provided to Asterisk for the connector?  Are you installing Asterisk via packages, or via custom-compile?

You've really given so little information that it's hard to guess what might be your problem.